# How do I construct this SQL query correctly

Tags: java, android, sql

I want to return the rows in my database that have the attribute in one of the fields equal to the parameter to the method. My code is:

```
    public Cursor fetchStatus(String status){
    Cursor mCursor =  

            mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_COMPANY, KEY_POSITION, KEY_NOTES, KEY_WAGE, KEY_STATUS}, 
                    KEY_STATUS+ "= "+status, null, null, null, null)
            ;
    if(mCursor!=null) mCursor.moveToFirst();
    return mCursor;
}
```

I want to return the KEY_COMPANY, KEY_POSITION, KEY_NOTES, KEY_WAGE and KEY_STATUS columns where the KEY_STATUS is equal to the parameter 'status'

Comment: Which database (mySQL, Oracle, SQL server, etc.)

Comment: That is my code that I have tried, and it fails giving an error "SQLiteException near "for": syntax error: ..". The database is SQLite3, and my application is an android application

Comment: did you try rawQuery? `mDb.rawQuery("sql statement", null);` Your code seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you may try something like this:

```
public object GetValues (string status)
{
   string query = "SELECT KEY_COMPANY, KEY_POSITION, KEY_NOTES, KEY_WAGE,KEY_STATUS 
   FROM DATABASE_TABLE 
   WHERE KEY_STATUS = "'" +status+ "'" " ;

   dbcomands part...

   List<object> =  execute db comand....
}
```

The error you specified in your comment might be caused by the lack of ' ' in you query. Just a thought.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I was unaware that you needed to use single quotes like that

Answer (score 1):

Use [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

You can simply specify your query and set parameters in search query.